# Taskbar can still be seen partially after hiding it

Tags: windows, windows-10, taskbar

I have enabled the automatically hide the taskbar in desktop mode option but still the taskbar is partially visible. Is there a way to completely hide it?
[image: A white lone can be seen at the bottom of the picture, it is a part of the search bar present in the taskbar]

Comment: This is normal behavior. You hover your mouse there in order to make it pop up. If you want to completely disable the taskbar, you will have to use a different shell. That will also affect the desktop though.

Comment: Turn on Small Icons. That should make your taskbar completely disappear. Mine cannot be seen at any point along the bottom of the screen, but mouse anywhere along the bottom and it pops up.